Can the read-read coherence rule infer the modification order according to the read value?
[intro.races] p16 says:

If a value computation A of an atomic object M happens before a value computation B of M, and A takes its value from a side effect X on M, then the value computed by B is either the value stored by X or the value stored by a side effect Y on M, where Y follows X in the modification order of M.

This rule commonly can interpret this example
std::atomic<int> x{0};
// thread 1:
x.store(1); // #1
x.store(2); // #2

// thread 2:
x.load(); // #3
x.load(); // #4

According to [intro.races] p15, #2 follows #1 in the modification order of x, and if #3 reads 1, #4 may be 1 or 2 as per [intro.races] p16. In this case, the emphasized "where" clause imposes the requirement: If B does not read X, it must read some side effect that follows X in the modification order.
However, consider this example:
std::atomic<int> x{0};
// thread 1:
x.store(3);  // #1
//thread 2:
x.store(4);  // #2
//thread 3:
x.load();  // #3
x.load();  // #4

If #3 read 3 and #4 reads 4, can we infer 4 follows 3 in the modification order as per [intro.races] p16? IIUC, the current wording(i.e. the "where" clause) does not mean it specifies the order for Y, in other words, it does not say something like: if B reads Y, then Y follows X in the modification order.
I wonder if the read-read coherence rule can be used to infer the modification order for the second example.
Update
How does the proposition logic work here such that one can reason backward from the observed behavior to the modification order?

What possible other interpretation could there be?  If #3 read 3 and #4 read 4, then it must necessarily be the case the 4 followed 3 in the modification order.

Yes, a loop repeatedly loading the same variable will see values in modification order.  It won't necessarily see every modification, but any values it does see will be in the same order as they appear in the mod order.  Unlike with stores to two separate variables (the IRIW litmus test), threads can't disagree about the order of stores to the same variable by different threads, i.e. the mod order.

@TimRoberts I meant [intro.races] p16 does not express this meaning. It appears to me that the "where" clause imposes requirement on what Y is but not specify the order of Y in the modification order.

@PeterCordes The problem is what the "where" clause expresses in the rule, as detailed in the question, the "where" clause seems to require what Y must be. If observed that B reads Y, does the "where" clause mean we can conversely infer Y follows X in the modification order?

Yes.  We read the variable again and got a different value, and the read-read coherency excludes the possibility of it being earlier in the mod order.  So it must be later.  It's defined earlier that the mod order is a total order of modifications to an object, which makes it easy to reason about this way.

@PeterCordes I considered the sentence after if as p and the sentence after then as q, from the perspective of the proposition, that is, p implies q. if p is true, we can conclude that B must read X or a latter side effect Y in the modification order, however, in the same case, under the same proposition, if B reads Y, can we conclude that Y is the latter side effect than X from the proposition? This is my concern from the perspective of the proposition. I'm confused at this point.

How would you reconcile the wording with an example, like if 4 was actually earlier in the mod order, but your loads read 3 and 4 in that order?  So another load could then read 3 again?  This all seems completely obvious and clear to me, both in intent and in actual details of the wording.

@PeterCordes See the updated part.

With your p and q parts of the sentence, you have 2 loads, one happens-before (sequenced-before) the other, so p is true with the first load's value being from X.  Then the q part is also true.  Rules like this are true for every pair of loads on the same object where one happens-before the other.  (They have to be, otherwise you could plug in A and B, X and Y such that there was a contradiction.)  I seem to recall a previous question of yours where the answer was the same as this, that rules apply in every case where they can apply.

@PeterCordes Let me try to understand how the proposition logic works here. Since p(a value computation A of an atomic object M happens before a value computation B of M, and A takes its value from a side effect X on M) is true, can p->q be true only q(the value computed by B is either the value stored by X or the value stored by a side effect Y on M, where Y follows X in the modification order of M) is true, the second load reads y that is not x, so q is true only if y satisfies that Y follows X in the modification order of M...

...Otherwise, if the second load read y but y wouldn't satisfy Y follows X in the modification order of M, q would be false such that p->q would be false, and the implementation would violate the rule, right?

We are not using the logic "backwards"; we're using it directly.
As you say in comments, this rule is an implication of the form "if P then Q", where P is

a value computation A of an atomic object M happens before a value computation B of M, and A takes its value from a side effect X on M

and Q is

the value computed by B is either the value stored by X or the value stored by a side effect Y on M, where Y follows X in the modification order of M.

We take M = x, A = #3, B = #4, and X = #1.  Then the antecedent P is certainly true (#3 does happen before #4, by sequencing), so we may conclude that the consequent Q is also true (modus ponens, if you like).
The value computed by B (namely 4) is certainly not the value stored by X (which is 3), so the other branch of the disjunction must be the true one.  Thus we now know:

4 is the value stored by a side effect Y on x, where Y follows #1 in the modification order of x.

If you want to be technical here, Y is implicitly bound by an existential quantifier, which they didn't write but which is clearly intended.  We could read it more smoothly as "there exists a side effect Y on x such that the value stored by Y is 4, and Y follows #1 in the modification order."  Let's abbreviate the subformula "the value stored by Y is 4, and Y follows #1 in the modification order" by R(Y).
So this statement R(Y) must be true of some side effect Y.  Now R(#1) is certainly false, since #1 doesn't follow itself and the value stored by #1 is not 4.  This leaves only #2.  We conclude that R(#2) is true, which tells us two things:

the value stored by #2 is 4 (we already knew this); and

#2 follows #1 in the modification order (as desired).



As a simple example of the logic here, suppose I tell you (truthfully) that "In this room, there is a man who has gray hair and is a famous author."  If there is only one man in the room with gray hair, you may validly deduce that he is a famous author.

We are not attempting to use the converse of p16, which would be "if Q then P".  That statement is not an axiom of the memory model, and for typical implementations it wouldn't be true.  If it were, then given the following code:
std::atomic<int> x;
void t1() {
    x.store(3, std::memory_order_relaxed); // #1
    x.store(4, std::memory_order_relaxed); // #2
}

void t2() {
    x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); // #3, returns 3
}

void t3() {
    x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); // #4, returns 4
}

we would be able to conclude that #3 happens before #4.  But the whole point of the memory model is that without more synchronization, we can't know that.  (For that matter, if #3 and #4 both returned 3, the "if Q then P" statement would imply that each happens before the other, which is absurd since happens-before is a partial order.)

In other words, as a rule, p–>q must be true, since p is true, q must be true. If B read Y but Y would not follow X in modification order, q would be false, which would make p->q false, this violates the rule, right?

@xmh0511: Sure, that's another valid way to understand it (proof by contradiction).

I heard another explanation «the standard says (P∧Q) -> R, where P is "a value computation A of an atomic object M happens before a value computation B of M", Q is "A takes its value from a side effect X on M", and R is "the value computed by B is either the value stored by X or the value stored by a side effect Y on M, where Y follows X in the modification order of M". it is possible to infer (P∧¬R) -> ¬Q, which is equivalent to (P∧Q) -> R so the standard already allows for inferences in both directions» What does "both directions" mean? I think it shouldn't mean we can conclude (P∧Q) <-> R
